# sums involving the nearest-integer function

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $r$ be a positive real number.  For each positive integer $n$, let $y = m_n x + b_n$ be the line that best approximates (in the least-squares sense) the set of $n$ points $(k,{\rm nint}(kr))$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$, where ${\rm nint}$ is the nearest integer function.  Does the difference between $m_n$ and $r$ go to zero like $O(1/n^2)$?

Failing an answer to that question, I'd welcome pointers to any known bounds on the difference between $\sum_{k=1}^n {\rm nint}(kr)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n kr$ as well as bounds on the difference between $\sum_{k=1}^n k \: {\rm nint}(kr)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2r$, since these could be used to answer the above question.

Comment: $r=x$, maybe?  As stated seems strange.

Comment: I made some variable changes.  Hopefully it is still the question you wanted to ask.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing typo in the original ($r$ vs. $x$).  Scott's emendation reflects what I meant to ask.

Comment: Since it now appears that the answer to my question depends on the continued fraction expansion of $r$, let me ask what the situation is (a) for rational numbers, (b) for quadratic irrational numbers, and (c) for generic positive real numbers (outside a set of measure zero).  Regarding (a): it's easy to show $|m_n - r| = O(1/n^2)$ when $r$ is rational, but I wonder how big the implicit constant might be.

Comment: It may be easier to try it from the other end: what exactly do you need? What is easy to show is that you never have $O(n^{-2})$ for irrational $r$ but if Alexey's reference hasn't resolved the question (I do not have an access to the papers he mentioned, so I do not really know what is there), could you just tell us what gap you are trying to span now?

Comment: "What exactly do you need?": I don't have a simple answer to this question. I have some ideas for variance reduction for Monte Carlo simulation, and if the simulation is supposed to estimate the probability $p$ of some event, then the most I can hope to obtain from $n$ (correlated) runs of my algorithm is error $O(n^{−2})$. But can I achieve this, regardless of $p$? If the answer to my original question is "It's not $O(1/n^2)$ for all $r$", then my approach to variance reduction may have limited applicability. (Here $p$ is the same as what I called $r$.)

Comment: I just now noticed Fedja's assertion that "you never have $O(n^{-2})$ for irrational $r$" (not sure how I could have missed it before) and am wondering why this is true (he says it's easy but I don't see it).  I'm also wondering whether sticking in a log factor would rescue my assertion (at least for almost all $r$).  That is, could the difference between $m_n$ and $r$ be like $O((\log n) n^{-2})$?

Incidentally, a better self-contained way to define $m_n$ is as $((n-1)a_n+(n-3)a_{n-1}+...-(n-3)a_2-(n-1)a_1)/((n^3-n)/6)$, where $a_k={\rm nint}(kr)$.

Comment: With $r = (\sqrt{5}-1)/2$, $|r-m_n|$ is $\leq 3.48854$ for all $n \leq 10$, $\leq 4.82222$ for all $n \leq 100$, $\leq 4.84478$ for all $n \leq 10^3$, and $\leq 6.6212$ for all $n \leq 10^4$.

With $r$ equal to Liouville's contant $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n!}$, $|r-m_n|$ is $\leq 5.15041$ for all $n \leq 10$, $\leq 7.76567$ for all $n \leq 100$, $\leq 8.56015$ for all $n \leq 1000$, and $\leq 107.402$ for all $n \leq 10000$.

So "$(O((\ln n)/n^2)$ for all $n$" looks like a plausible estimate for a full-measure subset of the reals, but not for all reals.

Answer (score 3):

The error term depends on continued fraction expansion of $r$. It is Khinchine's theorem. In the simple case (when $r=[q_0;q_1,q_2,...]$ is a Liouville number with convergents $P_k/Q_k$) for $n=Q_k$ the error term will has the following form
$$\frac{q_1+\cdots+q_k}{Q_k}\asymp \frac{q_k}{Q_k}.$$ It can be $\gg Q_k^{-\varepsilon}=n^{-\varepsilon}$ for some fast growing $q_k$.

Comment: Khinchin. Ein Satz ueber Kettenbrueche, mit arithmetischen Anwendungen. Math. Zeitschrift - 1923, Bd. 18, N. 3-4, s. 289-306

See also Kuipers, L. & Niederreiter, H. Uniform distribution of sequences, Ch. 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about mean square approximation, so I will focus on the sums.  A very partial answer is that, for $r$ rational and not $2$-integral, the sums $\sum_{k=1}^n \text{nint}(kr)-kr$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k(\text{nint}(kr)-kr)$ will be $\Theta(n)$ and $\Theta(n^2)$, respectively.  This comes from conventions needed to break ties and is specific to the case where $r$ is rational and has denominator divisible by $2$.  For the first sum with $r$ rational and $2$-integral, the sum will be $O(1)$.  A very naive argument using Weyl's equidistribution shows that, for $r$ irrational, the value of $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(kr - \text{nint}(kr)) \rightarrow\int_0^1(x-\text{nint}(x))dx = 0$, so there is an error of at most $o(n)$.  For the second sum, the best error that you can get with $r$ not integral is $O(n)$, as, for $r$ rational, the value of $kr - \text{nint}(kr)$ is periodic in $k$, while, for $r$ irrational there will regularly be values of $kr - \text{nint}(kr)$ arbitrarily near $\frac12$, so there will be contributions of at least $Ck$ in the second sum infinitely often.